# How do you compile static pthread-win32 lib for x64?

Tags: c++, c, windows, 64-bit, pthreads

It looks like some work has been done to make [pthread-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) work with x64, but there are no build instructions. I have tried simly building with the Visual Studio x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt, but when I try to link to the lib from an x64 application, it can't see any of the function exports. It seems like it is still compiling the lib as x86 or something.

I've even tried adding /MACHINE to the makefile in the appropriate places, but it doesn't help. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until it's officially released, it looks like you have to check out the CVS head to get version 2.9 of the library. Version 2.9 has all the x64 patches, but you will still have problems if you try to compile the static library from the command line.

The only workaround I know of is to use the DLLs instead of statically linking the LIB.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **vcpkg** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019). Which is the Windows package manager for C++.
It supports pthread building and also other open source libraries.

I wanted to use a static pthread library.
When i downloaded the pthread i got the dll(pthread.dll) and import lib(pthread.lib) i.e I can not use only pthread.lib I had to use the pthread.dll file.

So using vcpkg I have built the static lib. Which I can use without any dll dependencies

Using "vcpkg" you can build both Static and Dynamic Libraries

**You can use below steps**

Below i have added the steps for all DLL (x86|x64) and LIB (x86|x64) cases. You can build it as per your need.

Clone the vcpkg from git directory [vcpkg git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.)

From the directory where you have cloned vcpkg run below command- Which will install the vcpkg

```
bootstrap - vcpkg.bat
```

Check for the library availability by running below commands

```
vcpkg search pthread
```

Which will show you below result

```
mbedtls[pthreads]                     Multi-threading support
pthread              3.0.0            empty package, linking to other port
pthreads             3.0.0-6          pthreads for windows
```

As you can see it supports pthread for windows

**1 .Building Dynamic Library with import lib (DLL)**

**Building x86 DLL**

```
vcpkg install pthreads:x86-windows
```

Which will build the dll and import library in **.\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows** from
here copy the **lib** and **include** and you can use them

**Building x64 DLL**

```
vcpkg install pthreads:x64-windows
```

Which will build the dll and import library in **.\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows** from
here copy the **lib** and **include** folders.

**2. Building Static Library (LIB)**

**Building x86 LIB**

```
vcpkg install pthreads:x86-windows-static
```

Which will build the dll and import library in **.\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows-static**
from here copy the **lib** and **include** and you can use them

**Building x64 LIB**

```
vcpkg install pthreads:x64-windows-static
```

Which will build the dll and import library in **.\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static**
from here copy the **lib** and **include** folders.

**NOTE :**  Try to use with admin privileges

Answer (score 4):

For me, I just use a 64-bit windows compiler (mingw-w64 cross compiler in this particular case) then make (with2.9.1) like:

```
$ make clean GC-static
```

Or if cross compiling from linux:

```
$ make clean GC-static CROSS=i686-w64-mingw32-
```

Then how I install it for use (some of this may not be needed, of course),

```
cp libpthreadGC2.a $your_mingw_prefix/lib/libpthread.a
cp pthread.h sched.h semaphore.h $your_mingw_prefix/include
```

then to use it, you have to define this (example ffmpeg configure line):

```
--extra-cflags=-DPTW32_STATIC_LIB
```

Anyhow that's one way.

Another way is to do the same then modify the *.h files and remove all references to dllexport from the headers (or manually define DPTW32_STATIC_LIB in the headers).

ex header way:

```
 sed -i '1s/^/#define PTW32_STATIC_LIB\n/' $your_mingw_prefix/include/pthread.h
```

or even better in case it gets defined elsewhere:

```
sed -i '1s/^/#if !defined(PTW32_STATIC_LIB)\n#define PTW32_STATIC_LIB\n#endif\n/' $your_mingw_prefix/include/pthread.h
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it (VS2015). Should work for older Visual Studios too.

1) Download the release .zip from SourceForge
2) Unpack to a clean folder- should see "pthreads.2"
3) Open up your Visual Studio command prompt, navigate to "pthreads.2."
4) Run "nmake", no arguments. It produces a help message listing all the legal commands you can give 'nmake' to build it. For more info, see "pthreads.2\FAQ" file which explains their 3 different flavors of 'cleanup' handling.

I would suggest building "VC" and "VC-debug" (and maybe the static ones of those) only. The 'real' pthreads is a C system library on POSIX platforms like Linux, so only those combos are going to give you the exact same C error behavior on Windows that you'd get on Linux, FreeBSD, etc.

Comment: Hey, I think this is the best answer but it doesn't address one aspect of the original question. That is, how do you alter the nmake Makefile to cause the binary to be a x64 bit binary rather than a x86 32 bit binary. If anybody knows, please add to this post. It's very easy to change the supported nmake build configuration of "VC-static-debug", in the Makefile, to generate a release static library, say, "VC-static".

Comment: The way you do this is not by altering the contents of the nmake Makefile but by firing off the nmake script in the right cmd shell setup with the visual studio tool chain env, e.g. "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" cmd shortcut. These cmd shortcuts get installed with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

to expand kgriffs answer one has to do two more things to actually build a 64bit DLL and not 32bit DLL.

First download latest pthreads via CVS (as suggested [here](https://www.man42.net/blog/2011/09/pthread-w32-for-windows-64-bit/))

1) use 64bit build tools - achieved by loading correct VC environment settings in command line (more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx)):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat amd64`

(change the 11.0 to whatever version you are using)

2) As it is written in the pthreads Makefile:

> TARGET_CPU is an environment variable set by Visual Studio Command Prompt
>   as provided by the SDK (VS 2010 Express plus SDK 7.1)
>   PLATFORM is an environment variable that may be set in the VS 2013 Express x64 cross
>   development environment

which means, that if it was not done by the vcvars (in my case it wasn't) you need to set TARGET_CPU or PLATFORM (just in case I set them both):

`set TARGET_CPU=x64
 set PLATFORM=x64`

3) and now the final step:

`nmake clean VC
 nmake clean VC-debug`

this will make a 64bit DLL files (and proper import library and PDB). I can verify that it works with Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

[This message](http://sources.redhat.com/ml/pthreads-win32/2007/msg00008.html) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful in replacing "pthread-win32" with "pthreads4w" https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/ and compiling in MSVC2019 for x64 target using the console `nmake` command. Even statically link.